# Get the non empty data from a sql_varient column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-variant

I have a sql table with sql_varient column. I want to query the table to get the records which has value. I used following query

```
SELECT *
from Table
WHERE sql_varient_column IS NOT NULL
```

But its return the data which has no data also. How can I achieve this

Comment: can you explain your difference of `no value` and `no data`

Comment: for example if the column is varchar it should be is not null

Comment: you mean like empty strings? (`''` is different then `null`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the row for column `sql_varient_column` is not null and not empty:

```
SELECT *
from Table
WHERE NULLIF(sql_varient_column, '') IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
  SELECT * FROM Table Where sql_varient_column != ''
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this.

you can try it

```
SELECT *
from Table
WHERE ISNULL(sql_varient_column,'') != ''
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. Also, your last select statement will never produce any results.